# SQL : combine column value after filter

Tags: sql, filter, merge

I have two tables:
Table 1 i.e "mt000" contains: (Code, Item_name, ID).

| Code | Item_name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Red | XXXX |
| 02 | Grey | XXXY |
| 03 | Black | XXYY |

Table 2 i.e "vwExtended_bi" contains: (ID, Date, Sales_man, Quantities):

| ID | Date | Sales_man | biBillQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXYY | 01/05/2021 | Harry | 100 |
| XXXY | 10/05/2021 | Matt | 100 |
| XXYY | 20/05/2021 | Matt | 500 |

What I want to get is to filter by Sales_man then between two certain Dates I choose. My Table 2 doesn't give results where "biBillQty" column is null.

I managed to filter by one of the conditions mentioned above at a time but not both of them together. This is the best code I could come up with:

```
select
    mt000.Code,
    mt000.LatinName,
    (Case when biBillQty is null then '0' else biBillQty end) AS QTY
from  mt000
left join vwExtended_bi on mt000.GUID = vwExtended_bi.biMatPtr
where (biBillQty LIKE '%'  OR biBillQty is NULL)
group by
    mt000.Code,
    mt000.LatinName,
    vwExtended_bi.biBillQty
```

The goal is:

1. To get all items shown even nulls
2. apply both filters: by the Sales_man  and the Date
3. Combine the Quantities where the both conditions are true in one row per Item or ID

Example this

| ID | Date | Sales_man | biBillQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXY | 01/05/2021 | Harry | 100 |
| XXXY | 10/05/2021 | Matt | 100 |
| XXYY | 20/05/2021 | Matt | 500 |

To be like this for example if I Choose to filter by Sales_man:

| ID | Item_name | biBillQty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXXY | Grey | 200 |
| XXYY | Black | 500 |

Date is only to filter so it doesn't need to be shown in the result

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is applied ***after*** the `LEFT JOIN`, so you don't want to filter that way.  Instead, you should have `left join vwExtended_bi on mt000.GUID = vwExtended_bi.biMatPtr AND vwExtended_bi.Sales_man LIKE '%' AND vwExtended_bi.date >= '2021-05-01'`

Comment: biBillQty LIKE '%'  OR biBillQty is NULL : what is the purpose of this part? Like' %' means everyting that is not null but then you also select everything that is null.

Comment: show us your desired output based on the sample data as well.

Comment: None of your tables have a column biBillQty, but you still use it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Why `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are involved? Do you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: This one worked really fine for me and accomplished my first two goals
because it gave duplicated results. I still need it to combine the results in the "Quantities" column where the Item names are the same.
thank you for your time @MatBailie

Comment: I need it do display all the results including null values. I need all rows to be there even if they are empty.
Is there another way to do that ?
thank you for your time @Karlheim

Comment: Its the same as "Quantities" here. I forgot to mention that.
Thank you for your time. @jarlh

Comment: There was a `SUM()` before I update the code and share it here with you

Comment: @Nour edit your question and  add expected result into your question ,its not readable in comments , also try to explain the logic better

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)